# Is there a very stinky chemical solution that isn't a health hazard?

Tags: organic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry

An effective way to disperse rioters & looters would be to send an armored vehicle in to spray them with a very stinky liquid. Is there a chemical that stinks but is not  a health risk and that breaks down after a few hours, or could be neutralized with another solution after a few hours?

Answer (score 3):

My vote would be for [butyric acid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butyric_acid) and related short-chain fatty acids with between 3 and ~8 carbons (isobutyric acid, valeric acid, isovaleric acid, caproic acid, etc.)

In pure form these chemicals would be dangerous acids, but in dilute aqueous solution buffered at pH 5 or so, they are not very corrosive or toxic but are still pretty stinky.

Skatole could be another example.  See the Wikipedia article for [malodorants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malodorant) for some more ideas.

Comment: Indeed, many things like butyric acid come from decomposition or decay, vomit (as indicated by Wikipedia), etc. and can be smelled at *very* low concentration.

Comment: Actually, the interesting thing about butyric acid is that washing with alcohol (ethanol) would produce some [ethyl butyrate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethyl_butyrate) which smells like pineapple.

Answer (score 3):

Already done: See, for example, [Skunk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skunk_(weapon)) which has been widely used by the Israeli Defense Forces.

Per its [manufacturer](http://www.skunk-skunk.com/), Skunk is:

> A non-lethal ... deterrent [that] consists of an extremely
>   foul-smelling liquid, with the viscosity of water, that can be sprayed
>   over a large area using a standard water cannon.
>
> The Skunk is not volatile, it's inflammable – in fact, it can
>   even be used to put out fires in a pinch – and it poses no
>   health hazard. In fact, despite its outrageous smell, the Skunk liquid
>   is perfectly safe to consume.